# How can I read .raw multi label images in Matlab?

Tags: image-processing, matlab-guide, medical

I have two type medical images (.mhd and .raw). The .mhd are the header files, while the .raw files contain the actual pixel data. I load .mhd file with the following code, it contains a stack of 140 images (281x389x140).

```
[V,info]=ReadData3D('image-001.mhd');
imshow(V(:,:,45),[]);
Z=size(V,3);
```

and this one image of the stack:
[mhd image slice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgPRJ.png)

after reading the raw file which includes multi-label images with the following codes: 0=background, 1=class1, 2=class2, 3=class3, 4=class4,

```
fin=fopen('image-001.raw','r');
I=fread(fin, [col row],'uint8=>uint8'); 
ZZ=I';
k=imshow(ZZ)
```

it shows the following image:
[.raw file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtF6Y.png)

I have two questions:

1. How can I rotate -90 degree and show the mhd file correctly?
2. How can I see the correct .raw file?

I think I have written sth wrong, I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample MHD and RAW files please? All you are providing at the moment is a PNG picture of the raw file rather than the raw file itself.